# TreeView Within Data Template

Tags: wpf, treeview, datatemplate

I have an object that looks like:

```
List =
Parent+Child,
Parent+Child
Parent+Child
Parent+List<Child>
Parent+Child
```

Parent+Child have been flattened out to aid binding whilst I get this working.

I am trying to write them to a templated list box, using a different template for if there is 1 child, and another template if there is more than 1 child.  I have got this working, but I want to bind the Multiple Children to a TreeView, so you can expand out the Parent and see all the Children, but I am struggling to get this to bind.

Here is my code (in logical order):

```
   <ListBox x:Name="lsbGrandParent" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource dataTemplateSelector}" />

    <localutilities:dataTemplateSelector
        OneChildTemplate="{StaticResource dtOneChildSelected}"
        MultipleChildrenTemplate="{StaticResource dtMultipleChildrenSelected}"
        x:Key="dataTemplateSelector"/>

   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        int childCount = Convert.ToInt32(item).Count;
        if (childCount <= 1)
            return OneChildTemplate;
        else
            return MultipleChildrenTemplate;
    }

    <DataTemplate x:Name="dtMultipleChildrenSelected" x:Key="dtMultipleChildrenSelected">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                <TreeView HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource menuMultipleChildren}" Width="220" Height="100" Margin="0,0,0,0" MaxHeight="220" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>


    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="menuMultipleChildren" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MultipleChildren}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource menuChildren}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ParentId}" Width="20" Height="Auto" />
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ParentName}" Width="140" Height="Auto" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="menuChildren">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=ChildName}" Width="140" Height="Auto" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

But when it runs there is just a space where the treeview should be, and I have put a break on when the ParentName binds and it is not binding.  If I put the template code directly in the TreeViewItem it binds but does not display the value.

Am I doing something obviously wrong, or is there a better way to achieve what Im trying to achieve?

Comment: I should add that the listbox binding is done server side, and it works perfectly for the single child binds.

Comment: OK got a bit further one silly mistake where the style for the ListBoxItem was explicitly set Doh.  I changed the TreeView ItemsSource to be the List of Children and that works so my question really boils down to how do I set the ItemsSource for the TreeView to be the underlying data source of dtMultipleChildrenSelected?

Comment: I have found the problem and its a really obvious one!  The problem wasnt that it was not picking up the underyling data source, it was.  The problem is that the Parent Node was a single item, not a collection, and a TreeView can only be bound to a collection - I was thinking because the children was a collection it would work.  I added a Converter to Convert the Single Parent Item in a one item List Collection, and it works perfectly.